# How do i replace the color of my background using tkinter?

Tags: tkinter

I want to be able to fill my entire background with white after i have already put some text and buttons on it. I need it to be completely cleared off the screen, so i can put some new text and buttons on the new page.What method should i use? This would be really helpful for me.

```
    if usr_name in usrs_info:
        if usr_pwd == usrs_info[usr_name]:
            tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title='Welcome', message='How are you? ' + usr_name)
        # 如果用户名匹配成功，而密码输入错误，则会弹出'Error, your password is wrong, try again.'
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showerror(message='Error, your password is wrong, try again.')
    else:  # 如果发现用户名不存在
        is_sign_up = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno('Welcome！ ', 'You have not sign up yet. Sign up now?')
        # 提示需不需要注册新用户
        if is_sign_up:
            usr_sign_up()
```

Comment: Your code does not show how the text and buttons are laid out.  You can put the text and buttons in a frame.  Then you can destroy the frame and create another new frame to put new text and buttons.

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
roht = Tk() 
roht.configure(bg = "red") 
roht.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please consider elaborating on your answer rather than only posting code.