# I would like to somehow cove the entire screen with white so i can hide old pictures and text and button,then i can put new text on it

Tags: tkinter

I need it to be able to clear the screen and then i will add new text to it. I have tried the pack.forge method, but it doesn't work. what should i do? This is part of the code where i insert some buttons.

```
frame2 = tk.Frame(window)
frame2.pack(pady=30, ipadx=20)
frame_l1 = tk.Frame(frame2,width=100, height=200,bg='green')# 第二层frame，左frame，长在主frame上
frame_r1 = tk.Frame(frame2,width=100, height=200,bg='red')# 第二层frame，右frame，长在主frame上
frame_l1.pack(side='left')
frame_r1.pack(side='right')
btn_login = tk.Button(frame_l1, text='Login', font=('Arial', 20), command=usr_login).pack(anchor='w')
btn_sign_up = tk.Button(frame_r1, text='Sign up', font=('Arial', 20), command=usr_sign_up).pack()
```

Comment: You can just remove widgets from your screen using `forget_pack()`.

Comment: Do you want to _cover_ existing items, or _remove_ them?

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate of a question you asked a day before? https://stackoverflow.com/q/62226433/7432

Comment: I want to cover them, and no it is not